# StructureMap caching in a WinForms app

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, structuremap, web-to-winforms

We've been uisng structure map in WebApps (MVC) and it's great.

I'm using the same libraries we used in the WebApps, which has structuremap all throughout it,
in my winForms apps too. I'm having the obvious Memory Leaks problem, and I'm hoping I can address it via the caching in structure map.

Here are the types availible.

PerRequest - The default operation.  A new instance will be created for each request. 
Singleton - A single instance will be shared across all requests 
ThreadLocal - A single instance will be created for each requesting thread.  Caches the instances with ThreadLocalStorage. 
HttpContext - A single instance will be created for each HttpContext.  Caches the instances in the HttpContext.Items collection. 
HttpSession - A single instance will be created for each HttpSession.  Caches the instances in the HttpContext.Session collection.  Use with caution. 
Hybrid - Uses HttpContext storage if it exists, otherwise uses ThreadLocal storage.

Needless to say other than singleton and Thread local, they seem pretty web specific.

If I want to have the instances go away is there any way to do it without have one thread per "thing" I want to do, and completely serialize them?

I know structure map and using clauses don't play well with each other, but I'm stuck with it for now. is there a known trick to making them play nice?

Thanks,

Cal-

Comment: What is it that is leaking and why can't you dispose it today? It's easier to answer if you can post some relevant code.

Comment: You can implement your own lifetime cycle (by implementing [ILifecycle](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap/Pipeline/ILifecycle.cs); see [this Quartz example](http://develoq.net/2012/custom-structuremap-lifecycle-management-for-quartz-net/)) if Singleton, Transient or HybridHttpOrThreadLocalStorage doesn't fit. Another way might be to use a factory or Func to create an instance of the dependency that you need to dispose after using. That would enable you to completely control the instantiation and disposal of the resource.

Comment: [Jeremy D Miller's take on it](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/structuremap-users/a-gLr5jCWCA) is to avoid having IDisposables injected and let the injected services handle them internally or if you have long living instances, use a nested container.